# 2015 Honda Accord EX-L 2.4, I was adjusting the valves when I noticed a hose clamp stuck in the timing chain

Tags: engine

The timing chain jumped a couple of teeth, and I was wondering if I have done any damage to the engine by turning the engine backwards by hand? it made a full revolution if not more in reverse. Could I have bent a valve or done some other damage?

Comment: Does [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22708/have-i-caused-engine-damage-by-cranking-it-backwards) answer your question? As a side note, if you can bend a valve by turning the engine by hand, you belong in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. No human is that strong! The engine jumping teeth, yes, that can bend a valve, but only by cranking or running the engine.